# Regular expression for validates_format_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

Can someone help me write the regular expression for validates_format_of.

It should fail if any one of

```
< > $ \ any_non_printable_character
```

is present.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would work with Ruby 1.9:

```
/\A[^<>\\$\p{^Print}]*\z/
```

That will match anything that doesn't contain your bad characters and hence should work nicely in a validation. That will also match an empty string though so you could use `+` instead of `*` or add a length or `present?` check if you wanted to exclude `''`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Ruby, but for Perl, ... the following would work:

`if(/(:?[<>\$]|[^[:print:]])/){...}`

And in Python, awk, sed, ... it would look more or less the same. So hopefully this helps with Ruby.